# How do I write a recursive method that takes as an input an ArrayList of Integers and returns the smallest integer?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

This is regularly how it's done but it has to be recursively with no for, do-while, and while loops. if statements only.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arrayex1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Enter numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int num = input.nextInt();
            numbers.add(num);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if (numbers.get(findMin(numbers)) == i) { // If the 'smallest' index value is equal to i.
                System.out.println(numbers.get(i) + " <== Smallest number");
            } else {
                System.out.println(numbers.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public static int findMin(ArrayList<Integer> n) {

        int min = 0; // Get value at index position 0 as the current smallest.

        for (int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++) {
            if (n.get(i) < min) {
                min = i;
            }
        } 

        return min;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?  Are you asking how to remove the existing for loops?  If so, you should try it yourself, and  ask a question when you get stuck with a specific bug.

Comment: no for loop, do-while loops, and no while loops only if statements these were the parameters set by my professor and i am really bad with recursion to the point where i don't understand any of it really. The code I originally posted is with all the loops but i didn't know how to even approach it recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go ...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
        {
            add(3);
            add(4);
            add(6);
            add(1);
            add(9);
        }

    };

    final int min = findSmallest(numbers.iterator(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Smallest: " + min);
}

private static int findSmallest(Iterator<Integer> iterator, Integer max) {

    int min = Math.min(iterator.next(), max);
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        min = findSmallest(iterator, min);
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: Op said it needed to take an `ArrayList<Integer>`, but not sure how hard of a requirement that is...

Answer (score 2):

One way you could code it:

findMin should return int, take `ArrayList<Integer>` integers, int min, int index and be called with (integers, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0).

findMin should check to see if the value of integers[index] is smaller than min - if it is, it updates min.

Then, if it is not at the last index in integers, it'll return the value of calling itself with (integers, min, ++index).

If it is, it will return min.

Comment: is this recursion? the parameters of the question is it has to be done recursively...

Comment: @Suzy M Woodruff Yep! Think about it - The flow control of the method is calling itself.

Comment: I may be over thinking this but we can't use for loops, do-while loops, and no while loops...if statements only so how will this work? could someone dummy it down for me?

Comment: @Suzy M WoodRuff I only used if and calling. Isn't that exactly what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
int min = 2876529394; // Holds the smallest element. Put a number that you know won't 
                      // be in the ArrayList just to make the code simpler. If you don't
                      // have such a number, just implement a counter variable.

findMin( numbers, 0 );
public void findMin( ArrayList<Integer> a, int index ) {

    if( index < a.size() ) {

        if( a.get( index ) < min )
             min = a.get( index );

       findMin( a, ++index );

   }
}
```

Here, you're essentially doing the exact same thing a for-loop would do in principle, but instead you're using recursion.